# Unsupported command assignID with JUnit4 from Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, junit4

I'm new to JUnit and Selenium IDE, but I'm experiencing this error - unsupported command 'assignID' in JUnit4. Is there an equivalent in JUnit 4 from Selenium IDE? 
In Selenium it looks like this:

**Command** assignId
**Target** id=_globalSearchTextBox
**Value** search

**Command** type
**Target** search
**Value** Undergraduate courses

```
  public void testFindUGCourse4() throws Exception {  
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/index.aspx");  
    assertEquals("University of Birmingham - University of the Year for graduate employment", driver.getTitle());  
    boolean x = isElementPresent(By.xpath("//button[@type='button']"));
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.search-toggle.js-search-toggle")).click();  
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [assignId | id=_globalSearchTextBox | search]]  
    // ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]  
    driver.findElement(By.id("_globalSearchButton")).click();  
    assertEquals("Search", driver.getTitle());  
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Course results")).click();  
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.faux-radio.icon--radio")).click();  
    try {  
      assertEquals("Undergraduate", driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Undergraduate')])[2]")).getText());  
    } 
    catch   (Error e) {
     verificationErrors.append(e.toString());  
    }  
    try {
    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("courseresults")).getText().matches("^[\\s\\S]*Level[\\s\\S]*Undergraduate[\\s\\S]*$"));   
    } 
    catch     (Error e)   {  
      verificationErrors.append(e.toString());  
    }  
    assertEquals("Search", driver.getTitle());  
  }
```

Comment: I am not following your question.  Where is assignID referenced outside of a comment?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 It's not, when i tried to convert it into Java, it just put them as errors it didn't reference it. Unfortunately I don't know how to assign an ID to the element 'globalSearchButton'. If there is any way of doing this, it would be much appreciated, but i do realise maybe this isn't possible to do!